# Disable encryption for storage account

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-powershell, azure-rm-template

I want to create a storage account with encryption in disabled state. But by default encryption is enabled while creating a storage.There is no option in dashboard to disable it. I referred a [Microsoft API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/storageaccounts/create) and tried with the below request but its not working.

```
{
"sku": {
    "name": "Standard_LRS"
},
"kind": "Storage",
"location": "westus2",
"encryption": {
    "services": {
        "blob": {
            "enabled": False
        }
    }
}}
```

Response:

```
{"error":{"code":"InvalidRequestContent","message":"The request content was invalid and could not be deserialized: 'Could not find member 'encryption' on object of type 'ResourceDefinition'. Path 'encryption', line 1, position 47.'."}}
```

Kindly help me out to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting this error is because `encryption` attribute should be inside `properties` attribute. Please change your request body to something like:

```
{
    "sku": {
        "name": "Standard_LRS"
    },
    "kind": "Storage",
    "location": "westus2",
    "properties": {
        "encryption": {
            "keySource": "Microsoft.Storage"
            "services": {
                "blob": {
                    "enabled": False
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or other thing you could do is get rid of `encryption` attribute all together. So in that case, your request body would look something like:

```
{
    "sku": {
        "name": "Standard_LRS"
    },
    "kind": "Storage",
    "location": "westus2",
    "properties": {
    }
}
```

However I am curious as to why you would want to disable encryption at rest.

Answer (score 0):

I did a test in my lab with following scripts:

```
    {
        "sku": {
            "name": "Standard_LRS"
        },
        "kind": "Storage",
        "location": "westus2",
        "properties": {
        }
    }
```

But when I went to Azure portal and found that **the blob still was Encrypted**.

I also tested many other possible templates, but all failed to disable Encryption when creating the Storage Account. I assume that it may be caused by design : Azure forces each Storage account to be Encrypted at beginning.

If you still want to disable the Encryption, you can use following  powershell scripts to do this:

```
Set-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroupName" -AccountName "YourstorageAccountName" -DisableEncryptionService blob
```

You can see more details about `Set-AzureRmStorageAccount` in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.storage/set-azurermstorageaccount?view=azurermps-4.4.1).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi,@Deepa , If this answer is helpful to you, please  mark it as answer , so that we can help more communities. Thanks!